# Create a TBODY using Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array that looks like this.

[image]

now here is my code for that

```
success: function(data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    console.log(data[i]);
                }
            }
```

the `console.log` displays it

here is my table

```
<table id "tblreport" class="mytable" style="width: 900px; margin-right: auto; height: 18px;" border="1">
    <thead>
    //Table Headers here
    </thead>
    <tbody id = "body">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

my question is using that array how can I make it as a data in tbody?

Comment: You want to display those items in a table thats all right?

Comment: You need to show two info here. 1) Show all table headers and 2) Show one array in details like all the 6 elements inside.

Comment: sir lets assume that you have 6 headers. idont know what you mean in your second question

Comment: @kannan yes sir atleast in tbody since i already have a thead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you want this:

```
for(var i=0,a,tr,l=data.length; i<l; i++){
  a = data[i]; tr = document.createElement('tr');
  for(var n=0,td,c=a.length; n<c; n++){
    td = document.createElement('td'); td.innerHTML = a[n]; tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  $('#body').append(tr);
}
```

Comment: sir this one worked but is the best simplified code?

Answer (score 1):

This code should be working for you.. Put this in your success callback.

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/IBUmITS7V4ERUg2KBovx?p=preview)

```
var data = [['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']];

var tb = $("#body");
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  var tr = $("<tr />");
  for(var x in data[i]){
    var td = $("<td />");
    td.html(data[i][x]);
    tr.append(td);
  }
  tb.append(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tbodyHtml = "";
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
    tbodyHtml += "<tr>";
    $.each(value, function( i, v ) {
        tbodyHtml += "<td>"+v+"<\td>";
    });
    tbodyHtml += "</tr>";
});

$("#body").html(tbodyHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     success: function(data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            //variable to hold all incoming data
            var htmlData = ''
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i]);
              $("#body").append('<tr><td>' + data[i] + '</td><tr>');
            }
        }
```

let me know if this works.